# Current Location in Google My Map from URL

Tags: google-maps, mymaps

I want to be able to have phone users click a URL from a browser to open a Google My Map in Google Maps. Most importantly, I want the user to be able to see their current location on the My Map.

I am able to do this if the link is pasted in an email, but I can't get it to work from an HTML page. Here is the URL I'm using:

https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/1/viewer?mid=1sB3C0Ki-k5eLHI5qe3akUG0hKd8&ll=37.82978783458641%2C-122.45150260000003&z=14

You can see this link here: https://cityridebikerentals.com/test/

When I send the URL to myself in an email, I open the link (in gmail) and the My Map is opened in Google Maps. I can see my current location on the map.

When I click from an HTML link on my phone (iPhone 6s, Safari & Chrome), I see the route but not my current location.

I've looked at various My Map parameters to try to figure out the proper URL, but no luck.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

BTW - I am a small business owner, not a developer, so perhaps this is just beyond my scope. But I feel like I'm close.

Answer (score 0):

An iframe should be able to solve your problem, insert this code in your HTML code at the exact position you will want the map to appear, which it can as well be at the position you created a link with the name **MAP**

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1sB3C0Ki-k5eLHI5qe3akUG0hKd8" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```